# Do I have a future career as a SharePoint developer?

Tags: 2013, development

I'm a recent graduate with a BS in Business Administration/Management Information Systems. I've been working as an intern in corporate IT for a large company for the past year. I started with basic knowledge with HTML/CSS and now I have a better understanding of JavaScript / web development concepts from experience working on several SharePoint 2013 projects.

Although corporate IT handles the SharePoint stuff, I don't work as part of the official SharePoint development team. I work in the IT Project management office where I've done some basic business application development type work. My 'dev environment' is basically a SharePoint site that I have full admin access to and although I have full admin access, the SharePoint team has some company wide security settings that restrict things like editing certain site settings like themes and master pages. The 'development' work I've done is mostly HTML/CSS/JavaScript copied and pasted into content and script editor web parts or the .aspx files for the sites.

I recently received an e-mail notification for an MSDN account subscription. I didn't sign up for it and I don't know what this means exactly but they also remote installed Visual Studio 2013 on my laptop without notice. (I was using Visual Studio 2010 before that).

I read that with an MSDN subscription, I can have different resources like dev environments and stuff like that. If this is true, is this the next step in my development as a SharePoint 'developer'? I always thought that SharePoint development involved .NET programming/technologies like VB/C#. Is there a future for me as a JavaScript developer in SharePoint?

What resources should I explore to help me gain a better understanding of SharePoint development?

Answer (score 4):

First thing is SharePoint Development has bright future, very much demanding and good payout.
SharePoint 2013 is a versatile development platform for building apps and solutions with varying scopes that address a wide range of needs.

**What kinds of development can you do with SharePoint 2013?**

Developers familiar with SharePoint know they can build server-side farm solutions that extend core SharePoint capabilities. SharePoint 2013 offers a new flexible development model—you can use SharePoint 2013 to create apps for SharePoint that take advantage of standard web technologies, such as JavaScript, OAuth, and OData. And SharePoint 2013 provides you with functionality to interact with SharePoint resources and a wide range of hosting options. The new app for SharePoint development model gives you the ability to build apps that take advantage of SharePoint capabilities and that run in the cloud instead of on your SharePoint farm. This flexible development model, along with the integration of standard web technologies, makes SharePoint development work more like other kinds of web development that you may already be doing.

Follow this link to understand the development  and buidling your Dev farm and many sample code.
[SharePoint 2013 development overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164084%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Programming models in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163085%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

You mentioned you have MSDN subscription, i think in MSDN you get $150 credit toward windows Azure Cloud environment. which is really good.

If you have a heavy duty laptop then you can use Hype V (available Win 8 pro or above) to configure the dev machine.

You can also learn About sharepoint development over here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn448478

http://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=sharepoint%202013%20development#ch9Search